# How to ensure consistency between lookup table in database and front-end code?

Tags: database

I have a lookup table for skincare product categories that looks like this (integer ID and string name)

[image]

There are only 9 fields in the table, populated using a seed script, since there are only so many categories for skin care products, although this table occasionally changes (for example, I might combine Oil cleanser and cleanser into one category).

I use this as a lookup table to specify the product category in `product` table.

These categories are **also** used in the UI code (e.g. to populate a dropdown), and for that I'm keeping a set of categories in my UI code as well. This feels duplicative and I would like to have a single source of truth.

```
const categoryLabelsAndOrder = {
  OIL_CLEANSER: { label: "Oil cleanser", sortKey: 1 },
  CLEANSER: { label: "Cleanser", sortKey: 2 },
  TONER: { label: "Toner", sortKey: 3 },
  // ...
};
```

However, I need to also somehow keep UI-specific logic (like `label`, which is the text that gets displayed on the UI or `sortKey`, which governs the order in which they are displayed), and it's probably a bad practice to store these fields on the database.

If I forget to update them both in the database and the UI code, it can lead to bugs.

How do I fix this?

I looked into using `enum` types, but from what I found, they are supposed to be used for fields that are never going to change. `enum`s do not completely solve my problem either.

Should I run some type of validation in the code for `categoryLabelsAndOrder` with the data fetched from `categories` table so that the keys in the object exactly match what's in the `categories`? This also sounds superfluous, especially since I have to fetch from this table (and all other lookup tables) just to validate the consistency.

I am using Prisma & PostgreSQL, but this problem is agnostic of database solution or ORM.

Comment: "...I would like to have a single source of truth..." -- I've encountered this issue a couple of times. What I typically do is that one of the sources is actually generated/refreshed from the other; this is triggered by the build process or by another event. This way you always have a single source of truth. This can be applied to two, three, four or more copies of the critical information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

[image: table]

Add two columns to category table, one for the name in UI and one to sort the category in the UI, this way you can get the UI name and change the order (sortkey), also you can add more languages in the future.

I hope I am understanding this well.

Answer (score 0):

How is it a worse practice to store the sortKey and UI label in the database than having an entire copy of the products in the UI codebase? The sortKey looks to be correlated to the IDs and the label could be algorithmically produced using:

```js
name = name.charAt(0) + name.slice(1).replace('_', ' ').toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an extra field just for the name in the table may cause you trouble if you're looking into multiple languages.

Here's how I'd do it

```
categories


id | name
==================
1  | OIL_CLEANSER
2  | CLEANSER
3  | TONER
```

Then I'll have a separate files for the translations, format is depending on which library/framework you're using. Data will be returned as is.

```json
translations.en.json

{
    "OIL_CLEANSER": "Oil cleanser",
    "CLEANSER": "Cleanser",
    "TONER": "Toner",
}

translations.zn.json
translations.my.json
...
```

Frontend code will just render the translations instead. This way the truth is always in the DB, what's rendered is always the translations, and you can pass the translation files to translators to add/update accordingly.

```js
e.g

translated = translation[curr_lang].json

for cat in categories
   console.log(translated[cat.name])
```